# How to fetch Email Address in a API Link from SQL Database?

Tags: vb.net

```
        Try

        Dim webClient As New System.Net.WebClient

        Dim result As String = webClient.DownloadString("http://emailsendingnotification.herokuapp.com/sendEmail/toemail@gmail.com/TheTransactionisSuccessfull")


    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
```

In the above code instead of toemail@gmail.com in the API link, i need to fetch the email ID's from a database created in SQL Server 2014 Management Studio?

```
        Try 

        Dim webClient As New System.Net.WebClient

        Dim result As String = webClient.DownloadString("http://emailsendingnotification.herokuapp.com/sendEmail/+TextEmailAddress.Text.ToString()+/TheTransactionisSuccessfull")

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
```

This is what i have tried but nothing worked out.

The expected result is that a notification mail saying the transaction is successful should be sent on the email Address.

Comment: I don't understand. Where is your problem? Getting data from the database (and you haven't shown that code) or just concatenating the content of a textbox to your url?

Comment: Don't use Try...Catch like that: it will hide problems from you. It appears in many examples, but take it out of your code until you have time to use study how to use it.

Comment: Yeah use MsgBox(Ex.Message) before 'end try' if you want errors to show. or diagnostics.debug.writeline(ex.message). Btw these 2 lines don't have to be in a try catch. Use try only when you have tasks where u might expect errors and don't want ur app to crash it's why it's called "try", putting a string in result which is defined as string won't give an error. One last thing.. if you define something inside a try, you won't be able to call it from outside that try. Good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim result As String = webClient.DownloadString("http://emailsendingnotification.herokuapp.com/sendEmail/" & TextEmailAddress.Text.ToString() & "/TheTransactionisSuccessfull")
```

I see you're sending the string "TextEmailAddress.Text.ToString()" instead of the email as string "something@hello.com" in that textbox

Do msgbox(result) and you will see the problem